# adding map entry to <form:select path>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here's my code:

```
<form:select path="myEmptyMap">
    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${someList}">
        <option>${listValue}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

As you see, I have an empty map. I populate select with some entries from a given List. Now I want to create an entry in map like this `("someKey", "${listValue}")`

How can I achieve that? Also, I want to have multiple selects like this in one form. All of them will refer to the same map and I wonder if it's possible. Is it?